# Who founded the Argentine mate herb enterprise Cruz de Malta?

Tags: 19th-century, business-history, argentina

Who founded the Argentinian herb mate enterprise Cruz de Malta? This company sold herb mate for more than a century. Nowadays, the brand belongs to [Molinos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molinos_R%C3%ADo_de_la_Plata).

Comment: downvote for not showing prior research.

Comment: [This unsourced blog post](http://www.yerbamateblog.com/yerbamate_review/cruz-de-malta-yerba-mate/?_sm_nck=1) states that that Cruz de Malta brand was originally Chilean and only purchased by Molinos de la Plata in 2006.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cruz de Malta, a [yerba mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerba_mate) tea (herbal tea), was originally a brand of *Sociedade Comercial Francisco Mendes e Companhía* (aka *Francisco Mendes & Cia*), a company [founded by Francisco Mendes Gonçalves in 1874](http://ojs.econ.uba.ar/ojs/index.php/H-ind/article/view/1225) in Argentina and "[dedicated to the industrialization and sale of the herb received from Brazil and Paraguay](https://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/biblioteca-catalogo.html?id=34106&view=detalhes)." (via google translate).

[image]

*Francisco Mendes Gonçalves. Source: [Memoria Rondonense](https://www.memoriarondonense.com.br/calendario-historico-single/12/28/)*

[Francisco Mendes Goncalves](http://franciscomendesgoncalves.blogspot.com/) (b. 1847, d.1930) was Portuguese-born and [emigrated to Rio de Janiero](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283325780_A_Companhia_Mate_Laranjeira_1891-1902_contribuicao_a_historia_da_empresa_concessionaria_dos_ervais_do_antigo_Sul_de_Mato_Grosso) sometime before or during the [Paraguayan War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraguayan_War) (1864 - 70). Both he and future partner Thomaz Larangeira were traders who benefitted from the war.

A few years after the war ended, Gonçalves  went to Buenos Aires (Argentina) where he married and set up his company in 1874 to manufacture Cruz de Malta (and at least one other brand) using the leaves sent from Brazil and Paraguay by Larangeira.

In 1882 or 1883, they merged their companies to form *[Empresa Matte Larangeira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companhia_Matte_Larangeira)*, with Francisco Murtinho also a partner. By the early 1890s, according records in the company archives, Cruz de Malta was a high-priced, successful brand sold in Brazil, Argentina and Paraguay.

The Cruz de Malta farm was located in [Guayrá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guayr%C3%A1) (which straddles the border between Brazil and Paraguay) and remained for a while in the hands Goncalves family after Francisco's death in 1930. Francisco was also a respected banker in the 1900s.

---

Main sources:

*Paulo Roberto Cimó Queiroz, '[A empresa Laranjeira, Mendes & Cia. e sua presença
nos ervais sul-mato-grossenses (1903-1917)](https://ojs.econ.uba.ar%20%E2%80%BA%20H-ind%20%E2%80%BA%20article%20%E2%80%BA%20download)' (Universidad de Buenos Aires, 2018)* (link automatically downloads PDF)

*Paulo Roberto Cimó Queiroz, '[A Companhia Mate Laranjeira e seus fluxos mercantis (1891-1902)](http://www.aahe.fahce.unlp.edu.ar/jornadas-de-historia-economica/iii-cladhe-xxiii-jhe/ponencias/Cimo%20Queiroz.pdf)' (III Congreso Latinoamericano de Historia Económica y XXIII Jornadas de Historia Económica
Simposio 5: Transportes y Servicios en los Mercados Regionales y Nacionales en América Latina
(Siglos XIX y XX))*

*[Sócios da Cosan têm 50 mil hectares no Paraguai; no MS, fazenda em território Kaiowá](https://deolhonosruralistas.com.br/deolhonoparaguai/2018/08/19/socios-da-cosan-tem-50-mil-hectares-no-paraguai-no-ms-fazenda-em-territorio-kaiowa/)*

*[История одной монополии](https://www.mateman.ru/node/282)* *(The history of one monopoly)*

Comment: Somehow your links currently load very slow and sketchy. However wasn't the foundation 1884, for a bank "aparece el Banco de Comercio, fundado en 1884,"? That is: your link appears confusing towards the date given, NB: The Brazilian page giving 1874 has a very curious starting date! As the dictionary entry for erva & erva mate!

Comment: @LаngLаngС Concerning the bank, I'm not sure I follow you - he had no involvement in banking that I can see until the 1900s. It's not really relevant, just extra info about FMG. Your NB: yes, curious indeed (and it's a government site)!

Comment: Your number 1874 stands un-underlined, so I assumed *first link* is ref, but it only presents the banking date for 1884. So out of this similarity I inferred "mixup on your part". Then I read the second link after it finally finished loading and found that my already started comment was just *my* confusion. A matter of formatting?

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe I should edit that bit.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but my english is very poor.

> La yerba mate Cruz de Malta se elabora desde 1874, siendo una de las marcas con más trayectoria en el mercado de la yerba mate, uno de los máximos placeres de los argentinos. Es una yerba que cree en la autenticidad del sabor y en la calidad asegurada desde el origen. Elaborada con un cuidadoso proceso de cosecha, selección y estacionamiento de la hoja extraída de las plantaciones del Noreste de nuestro país

From Google Translate:

> The yerba mate Cruz de Malta has been made since 1874, being one of
>   the most experienced brands in the yerba mate market, one of the
>   greatest pleasures of Argentines. It is a herb that believes in the
>   authenticity of taste and quality assured from the beginning. Made
>   with a careful process of harvesting, selection and parking of the
>   leaf extracted from the plantations of the Northeast of our country

Fuente: https://www.molinos.com.ar/nuestras-marcas/cruz-de-malta.aspx

Comment: You could add the google translation yourself...

Comment: Looking at the translation, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

One of the members who founded this company was Francisco Mendez Gonzalves.

Comment: This answer would be improved by sources.